# MySQL Join two tables and sum?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have 2 table - `orders` and `orderdetail`.

I need to join them together and show the total. I can join them but how do I calculate the total?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders as o 
INNER JOIN OrderDetails as od on o.order_id = od.order_id 
WHERE o.table_id = 1
```

Comment: You gotta at least try to do it yourself.

Comment: I wrote it but I do not know how to do the calculation in it
select * from Orders as o inner join OrderDetails as od on o.order_id = od.order_id  where o.table_id = 1;

Comment: I cleaned up your question.  Better to show your table as text but that's ok.  Make sure you always show your work because you might know how much effort you've put into it, but without showing that it will look like you just copy-pasted a homework question.

Comment: Is there any way I can calculate it right in the table. I mean like that -- 

create table OrderDetail(
    order_id int not null,
    item_id int  not null,
    item_price decimal(20) not null ,
    quantity int ,
    total int = item_id * quantity // ??
);

Comment: @Reviewgame please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select a.order_id,
 order_date,
 order_status,
 table_id,
 item_id,
 item_price,
 quantity,
 b.item_price*b.quantity as total
 from dbo.orders as a inner join dbo.orderdetails as b
 on a.order_id=b.order_id
 WHERE table_id = 1
```

> **Update** : as you mentioned in comment if you want a computed column which automatically multiply quantity and item_price, then you need
>   execute this query :

```
  ALTER TABLE dbo.orderdetails ADD Total AS (quantity* item_price);
```

Comment: I wrote it but I do not know how to do the calculation in it
select * from Orders as o inner join OrderDetails as od on o.order_id = od.order_id  where o.table_id = 1;

Comment: don't use select * , instead it write all column that you need.

Comment: If I do not join 2 tables. I created a total column in the orderdetail table. How do I do multiplication? I tried this and can not.create table OrderDetail (
order_id int ,
item_id int ,
item_price decimal (20),
quantity int,
total int = item_id * quantity -> ??
);

Comment: @Reviewgame so you want update your table with new column 'Total' which should be quantity multiply price? because in your question you just said how to select and join two table. in my answer i wrote how to join them with a new total column